# Asp.Net Core JsonPatchDocument: How to inspect operations server-side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-1.0, json-patch

I'm just starting with PATCH requests in Asp.NET core with [JsonPatchDocument<TModel>](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/JsonPatch/JsonPatchDocument-TModel/index.html).

This class has the cool feature that I can add Operations like:

```
patchDoc.Replace(i=>i.IntegerProperty, 3);
patchDoc.Replace(i=>i.AnotherProperty, "AnotherStringValue");
```

Now, I can send this to my Asp.Net service and get a nice `JsonPatchDocument<TModel>` deserialized into my controller method.

But I'd like to validate that, for instance, "AnotherStringValue" satisfies a certain Regex.

Is there anyway I can find all operations that pertain to a certain member expression, like for instance `patchDoc.FindOperationsFor(i=>i.AnotherProperty)`? Or is there a way to translate a member expression into a path string?